# Generating a domain and IP blacklist with Bash

Tags: bash, linux, shell, sh, jq

This is a project to pull domain & IP blacklists from various sources and compile them into one list. There are some whitelists included that are applied when a blacklist is built.

It draws blacklist and whitelist source entries from [this JSON document](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/T145/the-blacklist/master/sources.json). The "rule" that gets applied is intended to reduce list entries into what is strictly either a domain, IPv4 address, or IPv6 address. Such a format is designated by the "format" field. Each format is placed into its own list, except the "domain" format which is included in all three.

Notes on improvements from any related aspect are welcome and appreciated!

[**aria2.conf**](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/T145/the-blacklist/master/configs/aria2.conf)

**create_builds.sh**

```bsh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -euo pipefail

downloads=$(mktemp -d)
trap 'rm -rf "$downloads"' EXIT || exit 1

# params: list name, sort column, cache dir
sort_list() {
    sort -o "$1" -k "$2" -u -S 90% --parallel=4 -T "$3" "$1"
}

for color in 'white' 'black'; do
    cache_dir="${downloads}/${color}"

    jq --arg color "$color" 'to_entries[] | select(.value.color == $color)' sources.json |
        jq -r -s 'from_entries | keys[] as $k | "\($k)#\(.[$k] | .mirrors)"' |
        while IFS=$'#' read -r key mirrors; do
            echo "$mirrors" | tr -d '[]"' | tr -s ',' "\t" | gawk -v key="$key" '{
                if ($0 ~ /\.tar.gz$/ || /\.zip$/) {
                    printf "%s\n out=%s.%s\n",$0,key,gensub(/^(.*[/])?[^.]*[.]?/, "", 1, $0)
                } else {
                    printf "%s\n out=%s.txt\n",$0,key
                }
            }'
        done | aria2c --conf-path='./configs/aria2.conf' -d "$cache_dir"

    for format in 'domain' 'ipv4' 'ipv6'; do
        list_name="${color}_${format}.txt"

        jq --arg color "$color" --arg format "$format" 'to_entries[] | select(.value.color == $color and .value.format == $format)' sources.json |
            jq -r -s 'from_entries | keys[] as $k | "\($k)#\(.[$k] | .rule)"' |
            while IFS=$'#' read -r key rule; do
                fpath=$(find -P -O3 "$cache_dir" -type f -name "$key*")

                case $fpath in
                *.tar.gz)
                    # Both Shallalist and Ut-capitole adhere to this format
                    # If any archives are added that do not, this line needs to change
                    tar -xOzf "$fpath" --wildcards-match-slash --wildcards '*/domains'
                    ;;
                *.zip) zcat "$fpath" ;;
                *) cat "$fpath" ;;
                esac |
                    gawk --sandbox -O -- "$rule" | # apply the regex rule
                    gawk '!x[$0]++' |              # filter duplicates out
                    gawk -v format="$format" -v color="$color" '{
                        switch (format) {
                        case "domain":
                            print $0 >> color "_domain.txt"
                            break
                        case "ipv4":
                            print "0.0.0.0 " $0 >> color "_ipv4.txt"
                            break
                        case "ipv6":
                            print ":: " $0 >> color "_ipv6.txt"
                            break
                        default:
                            break
                        }
                    }'
            done

        if test -f "$list_name"; then
            if [[ "$format" == "domain" ]]; then
                sort_list "$list_name" 1 "$cache_dir"
            else
                sort_list "$list_name" 2 "$cache_dir"
            fi

            if [[ "$color" == "black" ]]; then
                if test -f "white_${format}.txt"; then
                    grep -Fxvf "white_${format}.txt" "black_${format}.txt" | sponge "black_${format}.txt"
                fi

                tar -czf "black_$format.tar.gz" "black_$format.txt"
            fi

            if [[ "$format" == "domain" ]]; then
                gawk '{ print "0.0.0.0 " $0 }' "${color}_domain.txt" >"${color}_ipv4.txt"
                gawk '{ print ":: " $0 }' "${color}_domain.txt" >"${color}_ipv6.txt"
            fi
        fi
    done
done
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Minor nitpicks

While assigning variables from unquoted command substitutions apparently *is* safe, I personally prefer double quoting my command substitutions regardless of context - I find rules easier to remember if I follow them consistently. So I would have double quoted the `mktemp` near the start and the `find` when handling formats, but you should be just fine if you choose not to

You may want to set a restrictive `umask` before creating any files, to make sure access to those files is as restricted as possible. `mktemp` usually does restrict the permissions of created files on its own as well, but getting in the habit of doing `umask 077` or something similar at the start of scripts doesn't hurt

The way `aria2c` is used, it should *definitely* use stdin as its input file. This appears to be handled in `config/aria2.conf`, since no input file is provided by the script itself. This means that unless that config file includes the line `input-file=-`, the `aria2c` call will fail due to getting no input - or at least that's how it behaves on my system. It seems like it'd be neater to not rely on that line being present in the config file since we'd never want it to *not* take input from stdin here, so explicitly calling `aria2c -i -` seems like it might be a good idea

The file's name probably shouldn't end in `.sh` - the language an executable is written in is an implantation detail the caller shouldn't have to care about, so removing the extension should be fine. And even if you do want an extension, this is not an sh script but a bash script

The second series of `jq`s is a bit strange. To me there's no obvious reason to split the processing between two `jq` processes, or to use `from_entries` for that matter - as the first `jq` ends we have a stream of objects that look like

```json
{
  key: "we want this",
  value: {
    rule: "we want this too"
  }
}
```

Making those objects into strings should just be a single extra step, resulting in something similar to `jq -r --arg color "$color" --arg format "$format" 'to_entries[] | select(.value.color == $color and .value.format == $format) | "\(.key)#\(.value.rule)"' sources.json`

### The downloading part

I feel like if you're going to use `jq` to parse your data, you might as well take advantage of the fact that you already have parsed, structured data and a rather expressive language to manipulate it with. Serializing it to a less structured format may be useful if you need to do things `jq` itself can't do (such as interacting with the file system), but here we don't do anything `jq` can't do on its own. We just lose access to the structured data, named fields and well-defined objects for no clear reason, when we could just not leave `jq` in the first place. For example, in the first step, we want the mirrors as a tab-separated list, and we want an output line which depends on the file extension of one of the mirrors - as they are mirrors they all presumably provide the same file, so we don't seem to care which mirror's extension we look at if there are multiple, but your implementation looks at the last one and I don't see much of a reason to change that so I'm doing the same here.

So, what do we do? Well, having filtered our entries, we can keep operating on them - we only want `.key` and `.value.mirrors`, so we can discard the rest. Then, since `jq` has regexes, we can look at the mirror links to figure out the file extension and add that to the object. And then, with a list of mirrors, a file name and a file extension, outputting the two lines we want per key is simple with the help of `,`. All in all, we can fold all the commands leading into the `aria2c` call into a single `jq` filter:

```
  to_entries[]
| select(.value.color == $color)
| {key, mirrors: .value.mirrors}
| .extension = (.mirrors[-1] | match(".(tar.gz|zip)").captures[0].string // "txt")
| (.mirrors | join("\t")), " out=\(.key).\(.extension)"
```

Because of the simplified regex, this is subtly different than your implementation in cases like the `alexa_anti_porn` list - your implementation produces `alexa_anti_porn.csv.zip`, this one produces `alexa_anti_porn.zip`. It's not obvious which one you intended, but the rest of the program doesn't seem to care one way or the other as far as I can tell.

All in all, 8 of the 9 commands in that whole pipeline can be neatly folded into a single `jq` which we then pipe into `aria2c`:

```
jq -r --arg color "$color" '
      to_entries[]
    | select(.value.color == $color)
    | {key, mirrors: .value.mirrors}
    | .extension = (.mirrors[0] | match(".(tar.gz|zip)").captures[0].string // "txt")
    | (.mirrors | join("\t")), " out=\(.key).\(.extension)"
' sources.json | aria2c -i - -d "$cache_dir" --conf-path=./configs/aria2.conf
```

### AWK and writing the lists

Those last two `gawk` calls seem a bit odd to me. The first one just acts as a filter on the second - as far as I can tell, there's no reason those need to be separate. The second one also uses the `color` and `format` variables to rebuild the `list_name` variable that's already in scope when the gawk script runs. The use of `switch` is also a bit awkward - all the branches fundamentally do the same thing, they just operate on slightly different data. Using a map of sorts for that feels more natural to me. I *think* we should be able to get the same results with

```
gawk -v format="$format" -v filename="$list_name" '
    BEGIN {
        prefixes["ipv4"] = "0.0.0.0 "
        prefixes["ipv6"] = ":: "
        prefixes["domain"] = ""
    }
    !seen[$0]++ {
        print prefixes[format] $0 >> filename
    }
'
```

or even

```
gawk -v format="$format" '
    BEGIN {
        prefixes["ipv4"] = "0.0.0.0 "
        prefixes["ipv6"] = ":: "
        prefixes["domain"] = ""
    }
    !seen[$0]++ {
        print prefixes[format] $0
    }
' > "$list_name"
```

Granted, I've been wrong before and I'm no less tired now than I was then, so it's very possible that I'm missing something here.

Comment: In point order: 1) Are all command substitutions supposed to be double-quoted? Shellcheck doesn't complain and I've mostly seen my present syntax. Not saying you're wrong just curious 2) I've added the forgotten aria2 config; sorry about that

Comment: @T145 Huh, turns out not quoting command substitutions *is* safe in variable assignments, and they only need quoting in cases like `stat "$(get-some-filename)"`. No harm in quoting it either way, I suppose, but you're right that it isn't needed here. Bash keeps finding ways to surprise me

Comment: Another major sidenote is that I print each mirror on the same line delimited by a tab so aria2 can download file pieces from multiple sources or just have fallbacks. Your current implementation just prints out each mirror going to its own file.

Comment: @T145 I actually hadn't noticed that in my testing. I've updated my review to reflect that, clean up some code a bit, and add some more observations

Comment: "_possible that I'm missing something here_" - a full-stop at the end of the sentence?  I did enjoy that self-demonstrating line!  :-)  Keep up the good reviewing!